# Cloverage causing ‘Method code too large!’ error on a defprotocol

Tags: clojure

The defprotocol does have a large set of methods, 26.

I don’t need the defprotocol instrumented anyway so I’m trying to get the `--exclude-call` argument to work, but all my attempts have failed, I keep getting the `‘Method code too large!’` error for the defprotocol.

I've tried...

```
lein cloverage --exclude-call ‘mynamespace.main/my-protocol’
lein cloverage --exclude-call ‘clojure.core/defprotocol’
```

and other variants of the above.

Any ideas?

Ref:
https://github.com/cloverage/cloverage

Comment: This is just about impossible to answer without either your project code (enough to reproduce locally) or a detailed error message.

Comment: Have you tried `--ns-exclude-regex`?  Your protocol is neither a function nor a macro, and excluding every defprotocol, if you could do it, would be a very blunt instrument.